# folder explorer for server files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to rename/move or delete files from a web application (ASP.Net MVC) that are on a server folder just like how you would do it locally? I would want the user to be able to upload say 30 files (from a scanner auto-feed) into a temporary folder on the server (cannot save it locally due to data security) and then allow the user to be able to rename /move before uploading them onto Azure blob storage.

I saw few examples - jquery file tree seemed good but not sure if it allows rename and moving. Please suggest solutions for working with the server folder. I intend to delete the server folder after I am done transferring files to Azure. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by giving the USER that is running the ASP.Net application (defaults to IUSR) permissions to write to that folder.

Be very careful though, as you're potentially opening your website for abuse when doing this.

See: https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis for how IIS users operate.